# Force screen size when testing embedded DOS app in Windows 7 command window

Tags: c, embedded, dos

I'm doing some embedded DOS development with OpenWatcom (great Windows-hosted compiler for targeting 16-bit DOS applications).  The target hardware has a 24x16 character screen (that supposedly emulates CGA to some degree), and I'm trying to get the CMD.EXE window on my Windows 7 machine to stay at a fixed 24x16 without any scroll bars.

I've used both the window properties and `MODE CON: COLS=24 LINES=16` to get the screen size that I wanted, but as soon as my application uses an INT10 BIOS calls to clear the screen, the mode jumps back to 80x24.

Here's what I'm using to clear the screen:

```
void cls(void)
{
// Clear screen and reset cursor position to (0,0)
    union REGS  regs; 

    regs.w.cx = 0;          // Upper left
    regs.w.dx = 0x1018;     // Lower right (of 16x24)
    regs.h.bh = 7;          // Blank lines attribute (white text on black)
    regs.w.ax = 0x0600;     // 06 = scroll up, AL=00 to clear

    int86( 0x10, &regs, &regs ); 
}
```

Any ideas?  I can still do my testing at 80x24 (or 80x25), but it doesn't entirely behave like the 24x16 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, calling system() is not elegant (see below), but this is a pragmatic possiblity:

```
#ifdef deployed
int86( 0x10, &regs, &regs );
#endif
#ifndef deployed
system("MODE CON: COLS=24 LINES=16");  // includes a clear-screen
#endif
```

If you dont want to use system() you can use the consoleHandle to change the console-window back after your call to interrupt 0x10. Here are the functions for changing the buffersize and Window-dimensions:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687089%28VS.85%29.aspx